# Asp.Net Mvc search across multiple models using Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, lucene

I would like to use Lucene.Net as a search engine for my Asp.Net MVC application. So far I use Lucene to index one model object (including its child objects).

The application uses different models that are separated into areas in the MVC project. What I would like to do is provide a generic search form on the start page which makes it possible to search in all the models that are available in the application. The search results should contain a link to the details page of the object that has been found by Lucene.

When adding to the Lucene index a type has to be provided to the search method. Is it possible to do this in a more generic way or do I have to implement the search method for each object that I want to index?

Is Lucene the right choice for what I want to have as a result or are the other search engines that might be interesting?

Comment: You can achieve that fine in Lucene, but are you using some kind of wrapper for it? Because Lucene really just uses strings for the index fields at its core so searching multiple models shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, you can check out MultiFieldQueryParser in lucene.net to search multiple fields, so you could just map the models to the same structured doc and leave out the ones not relevant to a particular model.